# Wordpress - Retrieve blogroll links in PHP Array

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress Experts,

I am trying to retrieve all blogroll links in PHP array but not having any luck. I found function for retrieving in HTML code. Is there any way to retrieve list in array?

Thanks,
Mihir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But of course.  The [get_bookmarks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bookmarks) function will retrieve links from the dashboard's Links section.

Default arguments and use are as follows (taken from the above link):

```
$args = array(
    'orderby'        => 'name', 
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'limit'          => -1, 
    'hide_invisible' => 1,
    'show_updated'   => 0); 

$bookmarks = get_bookmarks( $args ); 
foreach ( $bookmarks as $bm ) { 
    // Do something exceedingly clever
}
```